# Combine multiple pgfplots from tex files

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I have been using Sharelatex to write my thesis and I have accumulated many pgfplots. I can't include more than ~6 pgfplots produced by csv files before I get compile time out. I have been dividing my plots among several tex files. Is there a way to combine all of it together in the end in a simple fashion? I tried searching and seems like one option is to convert pdf files to pngs and add the plots as images, but I lose the quality and sharpness of the figure (I tried imagemagick and was not happy with the output). What are my options, please advise. Thanks.

Here is one groupplot of many (as an example):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{15pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .65, transform shape,trim left]    
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 3,
horizontal sep=0pt,
vertical sep=50pt
},
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=565, 
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    no marks,
    max space between ticks=1000pt,
    try min ticks=4,
    xlabel={},
    ylabel={}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(a)} $15:60$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:\Lig{1})]
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg1} 
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg2}
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg3}

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(e)} $60:15$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:\Lig{1})]
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};
\addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};

\nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(g)} $60:15$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:Buffer)]
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};
\addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};

\end{groupplot}
\node at ($(group c1r2.west)!0.5!(group c1r2.west)$)[xshift=-1.5cm]{\rotatebox{90}{\large{Absorption}}};
\node at ($(group c1r3.south)!0.5!(group c2r3.south)$)[yshift=-1.5cm]{\large{Nanometer}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best option is to compile with a local installation of TeX so that you are not subject to timeouts. You could otherwise include the images as PDFs which should not reduce the quality, but you need to be careful to keep the formatting etc. consistent and you would need to produce cropped versions using something like `standalone`.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. is there a thread or link to information on how to do this? I haven't used `standalone` before. Do I crop each PDF using something like photoshop prior to inserting into the tex file?

Comment: If you use the `standalone` class to produce the PDFs, then they will be cropped by default so you don't need to do it by hand.

Comment: hi thanks again for your quick response. would you please provide more info on how to do this exactly? If I copy all the pgfplot script to the standalone what code should I use to crop all of them? Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you could include a small example in your question, it would be possible to demonstrate the idea. Basically, each plot would go in its own file using the `standalone` class. The default is to crop so you don't need to do anything special. Then you can include the PDFs using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Hi, I tried downloading Miktex and I also get something similar to timed-out, instead it gives me: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. So i guess my only option is to take your suggestion.

Comment: Usually, that means something is wrong. Even if a plot takes a lot of memory, once the page which includes it is shipped out, the memory should be available again. But if you have your plots like that, using `standalone`, when you compile, you should get cropped PDFs which you can include using `\includegraphics` provided you are using pdfLaTeX for compilation. EDIT: Not quite like that. Hold on.

Comment: Im not sure if its the problem resides in the plot or something else, bc they all compile fine by themselves, but when I try to combine all of them together I get the timed out, exceeded memory error. On a side note, I did manage to get the cropped pdf of the plot, but it does not crop it correctly, I am missing part of my plot, how do i adjust the crop? It is missing about 2 cm of the ride side.

Comment: First try setting the file up correctly. The code you posted does not compile without error, does it? It may produce a PDF, but a compilation error means that you have to expect erroneous output. Ignore errors at your peril ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this *because I cannot compile your example since it essentially depends on a file I do not have*. However, you want your plot file to look something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .65, transform shape, trim left]
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group size=2 by 3,
      horizontal sep=0pt,
      vertical sep=50pt
    },
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=565,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    no marks,
    max space between ticks=1000pt,
    try min ticks=4,
    xlabel={},
    ylabel={}
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(a)} $15:60$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:\Lig{1})]
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg1}
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg2}
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 1560 Por SG.csv};\label{1560porsg3}

    \nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(e)} $60:15$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:\Lig{1})]
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};
    \addplot  table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 6015 Por SG.csv};

    \nextgroupplot[title=\textbf{(g)} $60:15$ (TPPS\textsubscript{4}-\ce{2Cl}:Buffer)]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=10] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};
    \addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=100] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};
    \addplot table [col sep=comma, x=nm, y=200] {ST053 6015 Por blank SG.csv};

  \end{groupplot}
  \node at ($(group c1r2.west)!0.5!(group c1r2.west)$)[xshift=-1.5cm]{\rotatebox{90}{\large{Absorption}}};
  \node at ($(group c1r3.south)!0.5!(group c2r3.south)$)[yshift=-1.5cm]{\large{Nanometer}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In your main document, you then include the plot something like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{myfabulousplot}
  \caption{My Fabulous Plot}
  \label{fig:fabplot}
\end{figure}
```

Don't use the `figure` environment in the individual plot's `.tex` file. You just want the individual `tikzpicture` environment, for example.

You can also do this automatically. However, if you are trying to avoid time-outs, automatic is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work, however, I have to put `border=2pt` in the preamble, its not perfectly centered for some reason still, but it crops the whole figure. Also, if I can't include `figure` environment, how can I crop pgfplots that I made in `figure` environments, particularly `subfigure` where I placed plots side by side?

Comment: Use `figure` and `subfigure` in your *main* file. *Just* the individual plot goes in the standalone file. If you have several sub-figures, use several files - one for each plot. Then use `\includegraphics` within `subfigure` and `figure` environments in your main file.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh ^^ Forgot to ping again.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh You are using `trim left`. Perhaps you don't want that? When you include the plot, you can say `\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics{plot1}\par\caption{Plot 1}\label{plot1}\end{figure}` or whatever.

Comment: ok great, thanks for the advice. one more thing, is there a way to crop multiple plots from one standalone .tex file? I have about 30 plots and it would be quite time-consuming to make a standalone for each.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh Yes. You can do that using the `multi` option e.g. `\documentclass[multi, tikz]{standalone}`. However, I'm not sure that you can use the resulting PDF directly with `\includegraphics`. On the other hand, there are lots of tools which can 'burst' a PDF into individual pages, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh In general, I recommend keeping the plots in separate files unless you are sure you won't want to change them. I do it this way for figures because then I can compile and recompile the image when working on it without having to also recompile a bunch of irrelevant stuff which hasn't changed.